Only createServerContext is supported in Server Components
I am getting the following error when compiling , Next.js (page router) and graphql project using Typescript. Please advice , how I can fix it? Trying to get Json data on Apollo Server
   Warning: Only createServerContext is supported in Server Components.
     ⨯ node_modules\rehackt\rsc.js (36:0) @ throwNoContext
     ⨯ Error: Context is not available in this environment.
        at stringify (<anonymous>)
    null


Page.tsx
    export default async function Home() {
      
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <div>
          <UserComponent/>      
        </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
      );} 

 UserComponent.tsx
    "use client";
     interface UserData {
      user: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        email: string; 
      };
    }
    
    const UserComponent: React.FC = () => {
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery<UserData> 
     (userQuery);
    
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>User Name: {data?.user.name}</p>
        </div>
      );
    };    
    export default UserComponent;

